# Redirect 1 short url to 2 url using php

Tags: php, url, redirect

I wants to redirect one short url to 2 url using php. first url redirect immediately and second url redirect after one hour. when second url redirect after one hour, first url stop redirect. after one hour second url only redirect.

is it possible using php?

if you need more details ask me. thanks.

**More Details:**
I made an sort url tools/script. I wants to add two url at once on one sort url. such as: I wants to sort this two url at once `google.com and youtube.com` short result one url `example.com/gdh733`

when I visit on short url `sxample.com/gdh733` its redirect me 1st url immediately and after 1 hour 1st url not redirect, only 2nd url `youtube.com` start redirecting.

hope so you understand. if not understand ask me.

**Again Updated:**
Database:
[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfW0Z.png)
or http://devlup.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/database-structure-php-shortener.png

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]{4})$ decoder.php?decode=$1 [L]
```

index.php

```
<div class="header"> Php URL shortener<hr /></div>
<div class="content">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="shorten.php">

  <p><strong> Url:</strong>
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url"  size="45"  />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Shorten" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>
```

shorten.php

```
<div class="header"> Php URL shortener<hr /></div>
<div class="content">

<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","masudtoo_short2","masud226688");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("masudtoo_short", $con); //Replace with your MySQL DB Name
$urlinput=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']); 
$id=rand(10000,99999);
$shorturl=base_convert($id,20,36);
$sql = "insert into save values('$id','$urlinput','$shorturl')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "Shortened url is <a href=\"http://short.masudtools.xyz/". $shorturl ."\">http://short.masudtools.xyz/". $shorturl ."</a>";
mysql_close($con);
?>

</div>
```

decoder.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","masudtoo_short2","masud226688");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("masudtoo_short", $con); //Replace with your MySQL DB Name


$de= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["decode"]);



$sql = 'select * from save where shortened="$de"';

$result=mysql_query("select * from save where shortened='$de'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$res=$row['url'];
header("location:".$res);
}

?>
```

where i set 2 url and session php code?

Comment: Yes, we need more details, it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Yes it is possible and _if you need more details ask me_ Sir, you're not placing an order. **All your details and what you've tried should've been posted along with the question.**

Comment: I updated my post @julien-lachal and saad-suri

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible, using `Sessions` and `JavaScript`

In this example, I am redirecting every 5 seconds.
For 1 hour use: `1000 * 60 * 60`, explained in the code

> Create "index.php" with the below code:

```
 <?php
    session_start() ;

    //If session not set, redirect immediatly. First time only
    if (!isset($_SESSION["isRedirected"]) || $_SESSION["isRedirected"] != 1) {
        $_SESSION["isRedirected"] = "1" ;
        header("Location: index2.php") ;
    }

?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Index 1</h2>

        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            //After 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds, redirect.
            //for 1 hour use: 1000 * 60 * 60
            //                1 sec * 60 sec / min * 60 min / hour
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    window.location.href = "index2.php"
                }, 5000
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Create "index2.php" with the below code:

```
<?php
    session_start() ;
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Index 1</h2>


        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            //After 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds, redirect.
            //for 1 hour use: 1000 * 60 * 60
            //                1 sec * 60 sec / min * 60 min / hour
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    window.location.href = "index.php"
                }, 5000
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Updated code, discard the above code:

```
<?php
    session_start() ;

    $redirectsArr = array( //Pages to visit, by order
        "http://google.com",
        "http://youtube.com"
    ) ;

    //If session not set, redirect immediatly. First time only
    if (!isset($_SESSION["redirectedNdx"])) {
        $_SESSION["redirectedNdx"] = 0 ;
        header("Location: " . $redirectsArr[$_SESSION["redirectedNdx"]]) ;
    }
    else { //Set the index of the page to visit in the above array
        if ($_SESSION["redirectedNdx"] == 0) {
            $_SESSION["redirectedNdx"] = 1 ;
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION["redirectedNdx"] = 0 ;
        }
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Soon... redirecting to: <?php echo $redirectsArr[$_SESSION["redirectedNdx"]] ?></h2>

        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            //After 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds, redirect.
            //for 1 hour use: 1000 * 60 * 60
            //                1 sec * 60 sec / min * 60 min / hour
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo $redirectsArr[$_SESSION["redirectedNdx"]] ?>"
                }, 5000
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is good but i need more tips. i updated it. check it.

Comment: More tips for what do you need ? And what did you updated ?

Comment: After which execution, and on which page you want the user to be redirected ??

Comment: i wants to redirect 1st time google.com then after 1 hour youtube.com

Comment: Yes I knew that. I mean you posed 3 different pages in your answer, and 2 different sql queries. After which query, and in which page do you wish to redirect the user?

Comment: again update is my full code, i wants to use it. i wants to redirect blogger post url.

Comment: suppose `google.com` 1st url is default redirection before 1 hour and 2nd url is multi url (blogger post url) after 1 hour redirect. i am not good in english, so i can't understand you clearly. all process are using shortened url.

Comment: hello sir, you understand? @mario-a-rawady

Comment: Yes I understand, but you first said that you want a page to redirect to 2 different pages with a timestamp of 1 hour, and now the scenario is completely different. I can't understand the scenario, when to redirect to the first page, and when to the second, and are the url's static or fetched from the database ?

Comment: after 1 hour 1st url will be not redirect. only 2nd url will redirect always after 1 hour. i have not added second url on database. i can add this but how to set redirect option and connect with second url. i don't understand.

Comment: I really can't help you anymore since I can't understand completely what you want. You have my solution. Try to use it